# How to solve TypeScript error with axios response in React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got the following React function (using the alpha of React Hooks) that has a TypeScript error (thought it still works).  The error is pointing to the line of code where the axios promise completes with .then(a=>{setData(a))...  It is complaint about a I think.

> TS2345:
>   Argument of type 'void | AxiosResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
>     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'.

Here is a link to the code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/7zyx4vv6k6

Is there more that should be typed in this file? I'm new to TypeScript and was suprised how little I needed to do to make it only complain about this one thing.
In codesandbox it does not show me the tpyescript error that I can see. Is there a way to make it show up there like it does in my webstorm IDE?
In codesandbox, the line I want to make type correct is 32 even though it does not show it in codesandbox as an error

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useAxiosFetch = (url: string, timeout: number) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
    let source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    axios
      .get(url, {
        cancelToken: source.token,
        timeout: timeout,
      })
      .catch(function(e) {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setError(true);
          setErrorMessage(e.message);
          setLoading(false);
          if (axios.isCancel(e)) {
            console.log(`request cancelled:${e.message}`);
          } else {
            console.log("another error happened:" + e.message);
          }
        }
      })
      .then(a => {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setData(a);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      });
    return function() {
      unmounted = true;
      source.cancel("Cancelling in cleanup");
    };
  }, []);

  return { data, loading, error, errorMessage };
};

export default useAxiosFetch;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is in this line:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null)
```

Because there is no type parameter provided explicitly for `useState`, TypeScript infers the type of `data` based on the type of initial state. In this case, the initial state is `null` and TypeScript treats this type as the only possible state.

You know that the state will either be `null` or something else — but TypeScript doesn't. Let's use type parameters to tell it what's really going on.

```
const [data, setData] = useState<AxiosResponse | null | void>(null);
```

This gets rid of the error, but looks strange — why is `void` there? The reason for that is that you `catch` before you `then` — and since `catch` emits a side effect (returns `void`, in other words), the type propagated to `catch` is either `void` or `AxiosResponse`. Let's fix that by replacing `then` and `catch`.

The final solution:

```js
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useAxiosFetch = (url: string, timeout: number) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<AxiosResponse | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    axios
      .get(url, {
        cancelToken: source.token,
        timeout,
      })
      .then(a => {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setData(a);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(function(e) {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setError(true);
          setErrorMessage(e.message);
          setLoading(false);
          if (axios.isCancel(e)) {
            console.log(`request cancelled:${e.message}`);
          } else {
            console.log("another error happened:" + e.message);
          }
        }
      });

    return function() {
      unmounted = true;
      source.cancel("Cancelling in cleanup");
    };
  }, []);

  return { data, loading, error, errorMessage };
};

export default useAxiosFetch;
```

Comment: Thanks @KarolMajewski.   Just curious if you know what it takes for codesandbox to show typescript errors? Also, I assume that since my webstorm ide did not complain, TypeScript is happy with everything else.  true?

Comment: No problem! I don't know about CodeSandbox, but I know StackBlitz does that. I prepared an example for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bumnp9.

And yes, it seems to be fine now. ;-)